# fgets only read the first line of file

Tags: c++, c, fgets, fclose

I am trying to read a file from my .cpp file. I am using C libraries, so do not confuse on that.

So the problem is as clear as what I said in the title. fgets method can read the first line but when it comes to the second line, it cannot read neither the second line nor the rest of the file (since it exits when a problem occurs).

You can find the associated part of code:

```
void read_input()
{
      int i = 0, N = 5;
  char str[STR_SIZE], line[STR_SIZE];
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen("out", "r");
  if (!fp)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "error: file could not be opened\n");
      exit(1);
    }

  for (i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
      if (fgets(str, STR_SIZE, fp) == NULL)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "error: failed at file reading\n");
          exit(1);
        }

      if (feof(fp))
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "error: not enough lines in file\n");
          exit(1);
        }

      if ((sscanf(str, "%s", line) != 1) )
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "error: invalid file format\n");
          exit(1);
        }
      printf("%d\t%s\n", i, line);
      fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: `it cannot read` ... kindly explain.

Comment: How many lines are there in the file? What's the programs output?

Comment: I was just trying,  i will arrange those later. It is only for trying. Thanks. It is a naive code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe, the problem is there, because you've used `fclose(fp);` inside the loop. So, after the very first iteration, the `fp` is passed to `fclose()` and for any recurring use of `fp` in any further iteration will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as the `fp` is not *valid* anymore.

Solution: Move the `fclose(fp);` outside the loop.

Comment: @KutayDemireren if you use an `fstream`, it'll close itself ;-P.

Comment: Hahaha I will try next time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You are closing the file in the loop! Put the `fclose` function outside of the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i<2; i++)
{
    ....
    printf("%d\t%s\n", i, line);
    fclose(fp); // <-- here, move out of the loop.
}
```